# Is it possible to rename multiple columns of a CSV to empty columns name when using miller?

Tags: csv, rename, columnheader, miller

I have CSV files with headers like this

```
MyFirstCol,MySecondCol,MyThirdCol,.....MyLastRealCol,ppp,qqq,rrr
```

The columns `ppp`, `qqq`, etc I want to set to columns with empty headers. (I do not want to delete them!) So I want a resulting CSV with a header like this:

```
MyFirstCol,MySecondCol,MyThirdCol,.....MyLastRealCol,,,
```

(Note the empty, but present columns at the end.)

Is there a way to do this with [miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)?(*) I tried

```
mlr --csv rename -r '"^(.){3}$",' myFile.csv
```

but this command *folds all the matching columns into one*! :-(

---

(*) I do know how to hack this together with a search-replace command in `sed` , but I don't like it as a general solution, because `sed` is not aware of the CSV's column structure. Therefore I am hoping for a solution with miller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just remove the empty columns

```
mlr --csv remove-empty-columns input.csv >output.csv
```

If you want to use rename, the command is

```
mlr --csv rename -r '^.{3}$,' input.csv >output.csv
```

But **please note** in Miller you cannot have a CSV whit two or more fields with the same name. And if you have

```
MyFirstCol,MySecondCol,MyThirdCol,.....MyLastRealCol,,,
```

the last fields have the same empty field name. Then you can add a numeric progressive heading, then apply a search & replace to the first data row, and at the end remove the numeric heading.

Starting from

```
field1,field2,ppp,qqq,zzz
1,2,,,
4,7,,,
```

and running

```
mlr --csv -N put -S 'if(NR==1){for (k in $*) {$[k] = gsub($[k], "^.{3}$", "");}}' input.csv
```

you will have

```
field1,field2,,,
1,2,,,
4,7,,,
```

Some points:

- `-N` add and remove the numeric heading;
- `if(NR==1)` to apply the put verb only to first data row that here is `field1,field2,ppp,qqq,zzz`

Comment: No, I do not want to *remove* the empty columns. I want to give the (nearly) empty col7mns empty headers, but keep all three columns, just with empty column names.

Comment: @halloleo If you look ad my answer, there is also the way to have empty column names. Have you tested it?

Comment: I just tried exactly your rename command and it _folds all the matching (empty) columns into one empty column_! - But your answer shows me that I should make it even clearer that I want to keep the empty columns. Will edit question.

Comment: @halloleo I have edited once again my answer. Now it should be ok

Comment: Very cool. Does exactly what I want to achieve. A bit more complicated as I hoped for, but the workaround via the numeric heading is super smart! Thanks aborruso!